# Interfaces and comparables

Tags: java, android, interface, comparable

I have objects that implement an interface so certain methods are available (getTime, getValue, etc).

However I also want to force these objects to be sortable in the same way using Comparable but I can't define bodies in the interface (at least in Android Java).

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define bodies in an interface using the `default` keyword (which is not part of the signature):

```
public interface MyInterface extends Comparable<MyInterface> {

    @Override
    default int compareTo(MyInterface other) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

---

However, if you want to sort on different criteria from time to time. Passing a comparator with the `sort` method is a much better choice.

```
public interface MyInterface  {
    int getTime();
    int getValue();
}
```

Then call like:

```
List<MyInterface> list= ...;
list.sort((mi1, mi2) -> Integer.compare(mi1.getTime(), mi2.getTime())); // sorts by time
list.sort((mi1, mi2) -> Integer.compare(mi1.getValue(), mi2.getValue())); // sorts by value
```

Comment: What do you mean by not part of the signature? What does default actually mean here?

Comment: What if I had implemented two interfaces that have contradictory comparable methods?

Comment: @ArukaJ What I mean by that is that the ```compareTo``` method in ```Comparable<...>``` does not have the ```default``` keyword. But overriding the ```compareTo``` method with the default keyword is still possible. You can only override a method with the same signature.

Comment: @ArukaJ You can not implement comparable twice. So implementing 2 interfaces with contradictory comparable methods is not possible